# Dark, Unwanted Shadows Between 'leaves' when Rendering in Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, light, shadows, ambient-occlusion

I am hoping someone can help me with this situation. I am very new to rendering and texturing in blender and have not so surprisingly come across an issue that is preventing further progress.

I am trying to render in cycles a mesh that I have created with a particles system for some low-poly leaves. For some reason, when I render in cycles, there are very dark portions of these leaves that I can't seem to lighten, no matter what light settings I play with.  I thought that it would be due to ambient occlusion, but no matter what settings I change it doesn't make any difference.

I think it would be easiest for someone to see my blend file, It is here - [image]

[image]

Comment: You can upload a blend file here. Agree to the terms, then upload the file and paste the URL of this post into the box provided. It will give you a link - paste that link in your question. - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thank you for the advice! Here is my file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=LdnqoE26" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/LdnqoE26/)

Comment: Hey, you got it - I took the further step of pasting the link into your question for you. I'll have a look at the file.

Comment: Ok, So, I don't have time to dog too deep at the moment, but generally shadows like this are just cycles raytracer "doing it's thing" casting darker shadows where it detects another light occluding surface soon after a bounce. Most often the remedy is to simply add more lights. Perhaps add a point light with a low power and a very soft falloff near the darkest area and adjust it until it looks right.

Comment: Okay Christopher thanks for the help. I'll try that out and report my findings :) Do you think there is something I could do to the shaders on the leaves to help with this (if the point light doesn't work?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this just so I can post the pic. You can try this setup and see if it works. It should have a good effect, yet it doesn't seem to do much when I look at it. However, as you can see from the photo, the texture is missing in your blend file so everything is pink. This might affect how the setup is working on my end. Have a try on your project and let me know if it helps.

[image: ShadowRemoval]

Comment: It looks like what seems to be having the most direct affect on those really dark areas is increasing the Transparency under the Max Bounces under the Light Path in the Render Settings. I tried your suggestion with the Light Path but it's hard to tell if there is a noticeable difference. However, you have given me some other ideas with how to use that Node.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if the effect was diminished slightly because of your mixing with a transparent shader and an alpha value earlier in the graph, but play around and see what works best,